# dimension of vector space & polynomial in two variables

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Say that a polynomial with real coefficients in two variable, $ x, y $ , is balanced if the average value of the polynomial on each circle centred at the origin is $ 0 $ . The balanced polynomials of degree at most $2009$ form a
vector space $ V $ over  $\mathbb{R}$. Find the dimension of V .

I tried doing some calculations using graphs but didn’t find any proper approach to solve this problem

Comment: Did you try calculating this for some smaller degrees first?

Comment: Yes. But not happy with what i did. I couldn't find anything from that.

Comment: Taking the average is a linear operation, but scaling the size of the circle scales the average as the radius raised to the degree of that term. Can you show using that idea that a polynomial is in $V$, if and only if its homogeneous parts are? Combine this with the excellent suggestion by Tobias. IOW, check which monomials $1$, $x$, $y$, $x^2$, $xy$, $y^2$ et cetera are in $V$.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is incomplete, as it has a gap.

---

First, we consider a monomial of the form $ x^n y^m$, for some integers $n,m$. It is clear that if either one is odd (say $n$), then by reflection about the line $y=0$, we have a balanced polynomial.

By symmetry about the line $y=x$, terms of the form $ x^{2n}y^{2m} - x^{2m} y^{2n}$ are also balanced.

It remains to consider polynomials which are made up solely of terms of the form $ x^{2n} y^{2m} $, where $ n \geq m$. It is not clear to me if these are all.

Comment: @sammath Sorry, but I just realized that this is incomplete. It does not show that some linear combination will not work, e.g. $ x^2 - y^2 $, which (I believe) is balanced.

Comment: +1 for proving me wrong that we cannot do this on a term by term basis.

Answer (score 2):

Supplementing Calvin Lin's answer by the following observations.

- Monomials of different degrees scale differently as a function of the radius, so a polynomial is in the space $V$, iff all its homogeneous parts are.
- It suffices to test a homogeneous polynomial on the unit circle.
- The expected value of a form of an odd degree is automatically zero: $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$ negates everything.
- The expected value (=the average) of a form $F(x,y):=\sum_{i=0}^{2k}a_ix^iy^{2k-i}$ of an even degree $2k$,  is 
  $$
  E(F)=\sum_{i=0}^{2k}a_i E(x^iy^{2k-i})=\sum_{i=0, 2\mid i}^{2k} a_iE(x^iy^{2k-i}).
  $$
  Here all the expected values $E(x^iy^{2k-i})$ are clearly positive ($i$ even), so the constraint $E(F)=0$ determines one (any one) of the coefficients $a_i$, $2\mid i$, as a linear combination of the others.
- Therefore we get a single linear constraint on the coefficients of forms of a given even degree to be balanced, and no other constraints.
- The space of (bivariate) forms of degree $m$ has dimension $m+1$, so the answer is
  $$\dim V=\sum_{k=0}^{2009}(m+1)-\sum_{k=0,2\mid k}^{2009}1.$$ Leaving the calculation of this sum to you :-)

Comment: +1 Nice. Just a pet peeve, $ 2 \mid 0$, so the notation $k=0$ is redundant.